# Ionic 3 ion-select disable text selection

Tags: ionic3

I have my ion select customized

```
<ion-item class="dias">
  <ion-label>Lunes a Sabado</ion-label>
  <ion-select (ionChange)="selectedDays($event)">
    <ion-option value="0">Lunes a Viernes</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="1">Lunes a Sabado</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

This is how it looks like

[image]

But, when I select some value, this is the result:

[image]

What I want is to prevent the selected text because I want to put the selected text value in the label(right position). I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="selectedDays($event)" interface="popover" selectedText=" ">
    <ion-option value="0">Lunes a Viernes</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="1">Lunes a Sabado</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Set the Attr selectedText=" " with a white space for prevent the selected text

Answer (score 0):

You can give 100% width to ion-select.

```
ion-select{
   width:100%;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   padding: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```